# Conversion of .pl and .vpl files in windows

Tags: fonts, installing, miktex, windows

I am trying to install a type 1 font in MiKTeX, I use Windows Seven. I am using fontinst and following step by step the guide here http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/info/Type1fonts/fontinstallationguide/fontinstallationguide.pdf

Nonetheless, I have no idea on how to convert the .pl and .vpl files into .tfm and .vf files respectively. In the guide, this is explained on page 16, §1.3. It talks about Bash shell but, honesty, I am really not an expert and don't even know what that is.

So, what should I do? Thank you very much.

Comment: I should preface this by saying that I know nothing about Windows. Does MikTeX include binaries for pltotf and vptovf? Those are the key commands there. The rest is just wrapping those commands in a loop to iterate over all of the relevant files. Basically, it is telling you to run pltotf <filename>.pl and vptovf <filename>.vf for each .pl and .vf file. I guess you would do this at the command line. I don't know how you would automatically run the command for all of the files in Windows, though.

Comment: You may install cygwin in Windows 7, and you can try the commands in cygwin shell.

Comment: It is really not necessary to install cygwin to run a simple command line tool in windows. Open a command line by holding down the shift key and then right-clicking in the windows explorer on the folder with the vpl-files: Then the context menu will show "open command line here". In the command line you can then type the command e.g. `vptovf  VPLFILE VFFILE TFMFILE`. The command line can also loop over all files, check some documentation. There is also a powershell in windows which you can use too.